# Scilab: Finding Max Number in CSV

Tags: csv, max, scilab

Just started on scilab, I'm trying to extract csv file and search for the highest value from the data set in a specific column with print out of a line "The highest value is X."

```
function Max_Value()
    fid=mopen("D:/Q2/hrr_plastic_chair.csv")
    m=max(:, column);
    disp ("The highest value is:",m)
    mclose(fid)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `csvRead(filename, separator, decimal)` to recover a matrix from your csv file. Change `separator` (default is ",") and `decimal` (default is ".") if they are not the default. In any case see read the `csvRead` help page.